# Dynamic redirect .htaccess not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don't know much about .htaccess and redirects, what am I not doing right?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_pais=(.*)&id_provincia=(.*)&id_comunidad=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/comunidades/$1/slug? [R=301,L]
```

I want that `$1 = id_comunidad` but the result of this redirect is: `https://example.com/comunidades//slug`
I used `%1` too instead `$1` and the result always is: `https://example.com/comunidades/1/slug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, I had to pass it as third parameter `%3`, not as first `%1`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_pais=(.*)&id_provincia=(.*)&id_comunidad=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/comunidades/%3/slug? [R=301,L]
```